# При попытке задать URL в axWindowsMediaPlayer1 ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

Tags: c#, исключения, mediaplayer

При попытке задать URL в `axWindowsMediaPlayer1` ошибка: `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта`. Сам объект реально существует. Код видеопроигрывателя скопирован с другой формы, где всё работает.

```
public partial class Video : Slide
{
    public AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1;
    public string bpath;
    public PictureBox video;

    public Video(string apath, string bpath) : base (apath) // apath  - путь к фото из класса Slide, bpath - путь к видео
    {
        this.bpath = bpath;
        this.video = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.video.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.video.BackgroundImage = global::StPavel_TheForestSong.Properties.Resources.video2;
        this.video.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.video.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        this.video.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(387, 162);
        this.video.Name = "video";
        this.video.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 70);
        this.video.TabStop = false;
        this.video.Click += new System.EventHandler(video_Click);
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Enabled = true;
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(79, 12);
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Name = "axWindowsMediaPlayer1";
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Video));
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState")));
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(430, 280);
        this.Controls.Add(this.video);
        this.Controls.Add(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
    }

    private void video_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneSlide(0);
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = true;
    }

    public override void oneSlide(int i) // показывает одно видео
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "G:\\mf.mp4";
    }
}
```

Comment: Если не задавать URL, то сам плеер показывается на форме

Comment: Если что было более лаконично просто `NullReferenceException` вместо сообщения `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта`.

Comment: А вы пробовали отлаживать ваш вариант и рабочий?

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov 
Отлаживать в каком смысле?

Comment: Ставить точку останова (breakpoint) и проходить по шагам. Понимаете меня или надо детальней пояснить? Мне это несложно если что.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov нет, так не пробовала. А где там можно поставить точки останова? Плеер то на форме показывается. Он не хочет принимать ссылку на файл, который нужно воспроизвести. И я попробовала MessageBox.Show(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL) - выдает такую же ошибку.

Comment: Смотрите: 1. Берёте рабочий пример и отлаживаете рабочий код на том месте где у вас не работает. 2. Затем, выяснив что-то новое с помощью пошаговой отладки, переносите ваши результаты на нерабочий код и пробуете это. 3. Если получилось выкладываете ваш ответ, если не получилось, выкладываете новые детали в вопрос, редактируя его. Общий совет: отлаживайте ваши приложения, не используйте `MessageBox.Show` для этих целей. Это неэффективно.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov все работает, если задокументировать одну строчку:  axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "G:\\mf.mp4"; Поэтому даже не представляю где можно поставить точку останова

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобралась. Класс Video является наследником Slide и метод oneSlide в нем прегружается. Но этот метод вызывается в процессе инициализации родителя Slide. Естественно, исходный класс не воспринимает перегруженный метод.